# Layout: moving the stock element in between the qty and addtocart

Tags: magento2, layout, template

My want is to move the "In stock" part in between the "Qty" and "Add to Cart" button; However this is made hard by the fact that these two components are in the same template and not wrapped in a container or block, so I can't use the xml to move the "stock" before or after these elements.

What would be a good approach to get this result?
[image: the content in the green square, moved to where the red line is]

Comment: Why you don't want edit `list.phtml`?

Comment: Hello @Evgeny, image is for product view page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `product/view/addtocart.phtml` file of your theme and add below code snippet between qty and action button div :

```
<?php if ($block->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>
            <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
                <div class="stock available" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Availability') ?>">
                    <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('In stock') ?></span>
                </div>
            <?php else: ?>
                <div class="stock unavailable" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Availability') ?>">
                    <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Out of stock') ?></span>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

it will show stock availability status between qty and add to cart button

Comment: That actually did it; I was afraid this might conflict with removing it in the .xml but not calling the child html must mean it stays there separately. Thanks Naveed!

Comment: wow! thank you very much @naveed-asim. so save my day. many times I struggled in xml to move its position, it turns out that there is this simple way.